# code that active keyboard keys with the mouse position

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make a script that whatever my mouse goes to the left it active and holds A, and when my mouse goes to the right it actives and holds D, I am new at the AutoHotkey so I don't know how to do that,'
I did this script but I don't know if its works

```
Esc::ExitApp
Loop, 99999999999
{
MouseGetPos
if (x < 683)
Send A
} else if (x > 683) {
Send D
}
Return
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "my mouse go to the left it active and holds A"? Do you want the program to hold down 'A' if you mouse is positioned the left half of your screen and 'D' for the right half?

Comment: yes, i want the program to hold down A if the mouse is positioned to the left half of the screen and D for the right half

Answer (score 0):

This script should do what you want it to do. A couple of key points though:

- `Loop, 99999999999`: If you want an infinite loop, just use [`Loop`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) with no additional parameters.
- [`MouseGetPos`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm): If you want to track the mouse position, you need to first provide a variable that you want to use to store the x/y coordinates. In this case, to remain consistent with the rest of your code, I chose to use `MouseGetPos, x` to store the x-coordinate as the variable `x` to stay consistent with the rest of your code.
- [`Send`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm): From the [section of the Docs about holding down keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Repeating_or_Holding_Down_a_Key):

> To hold down or release a key: Enclose in braces the name of the key followed by the word Down or Up. For example:
>
> ```
> Send {b down}{b up} 
> Send {TAB down}{TAB up} 
> Send {Up down}  ;Press down the up-arrow key. 
> Sleep 1000  ; Keep it down for one second. 
> Send {Up up}  ; Release the up-arrow key.
> ```

Final Code:

```
Loop
    {
    MouseGetPos, x
    if (x < 683){
        Send {a down}
        while(x < 683){
            MouseGetPos, x
            Sleep 1
        }
        Send {a up}
    }
     else if (x > 683) {
        Send {d down}
        while(x > 683){
            MouseGetPos, x
            Sleep 1
        }
        Send {d up}
    }
}
Return
Esc::ExitApp
```

If it doesn't work how you want it to, just lmk what about it is not working properly and I would be glad to make revisions.

Comment: OMG,Thank you for helping me!

Comment: If it solved your problem, could you please mark it as the solution? @Adryanzoivermei

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, what program/ game are you using it with?